# How to cache an image array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, caching

I'm trying to make an Image sequence scrolling website, something like Apple Airpod Pro.

I'm facing an issue with images loading, each image will load once it displays only. 
It appears that I have to preload all images on dom to cache it out so it'll look smooth when scrolling.

So I'm looking for a better way to cache my images
Here is my image array :

```
  const MAX = 4875; //last image number
  const PREFIX = "images/image-scroll/Test_";   //image location
  const EXT = ".jpg";   //image format
  var images = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= MAX; i += 1) {
    images.push(
      PREFIX + ("00000" + i).slice(-5) + EXT
    );
  }
```

Currently, I'm preloading images this way:

```
    //Preload Images 
  jQuery('document').ready(function(){

    jQuery.each(images, function() {
      jQuery('<img />').attr('src', this).appendTo('body').hide();
    });

  });
```

This method works, but it makes the site heavy and it'll keep creating img elements every time you update the page.

Is it possible if I can just load all images to cache it without adding elements to the code?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to call `GET` requests to the `image URLS` directly instead of waiting for browser to call it from the `DOM element`. This way the DOM is not modified and the images **may be** cached in the browser.

The network and caching layers should work similarly to how it would if you had added it to DOM.

```
 //Preload Images 
  jQuery('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery.each(images, function() {
      fetch(this); // uses the fetch API to do a get request. You may use the jQuery AJAX if required.
    });
  });
```

Comment: I've tried your way, but the site is getting slower and images loads again when it's shown

Comment: the issue could be that there are far too many images than can be held in the cache. So, the cache gets overwritten after a few MBs and creates a cache miss soon enough. You could try caching fewer images and may be also set a timeout across fetch with 100ms, say such that the entire set of requests are not sent all at once